# how to push branch to gitlab with command line

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a propject that have a `master` branch.

[image]

T create a new `branch` with this command.

```
$   git branch develop
$   git checkout develop
```

when I look the gitlab(local), `develop branch` is not added to my project/branch.

after the switch to `develop branch` and I made many changed to the `develop branch`.

I need to commit and push the `develop branch` to gitlab(local).

I know that if I create new `branch` from gitlab(local) then I can `clone` and commit and ...

but I need to to `push` the created `branch` from `repo` to gitlab(local) with command line.

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to push develop branch into origin? `git push origin develop`... perhaps even use `--set-upstream` so that the local branch starts tracking the remote one,

Comment: @stud3nt , my problem with displayed it on git(local).
I no problem with `create` branch.

Comment: @phd, I saw that question before, and no problem with `create branch`, my problem with displayed it on git(local). I mentioned in  prev comment.

Comment: The linked answer shows both creation and pushing and pushing is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what `git branch -avv` tells you about your current branches.

The `develop` branch should be associated with an `origin/develop`, which means the dropbox (where you see "`master`" in your screenshot) should now include "`develop`".

But no new commits were pushed, since you have created `develop` where `master` is, which is why the last "update" is still the one done on `master`.

Comment: @A.R.F Sorry, I meant git branch: br is an alias.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

I realized that as long as I didn't commit and push from the new branch (develop), It does't appear in git server.

this resolved with `commit` and `push` the `develop` branch.

I did this:

```
git commit -m "..."
git push -u origin develop
```

then `develop` branch appear in git server.

I hope is useful.

Comment: You had selected the right answer before, why change now?